# Can't find executable (pipsi) in my PATH even though my PATH is set correctly and permissions are also correct in ZSH

Tags: macos, zsh, path, oh-my-zsh, exec

I have just installed `pipsi`.  I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite and I'm using iTerm and running `zsh` via `oh-my-zsh`.

My problem is that I get the following:

```bash
~ >>> pipsi
zsh: command not found: pipsi


~ >>> which pipsi
pipsi not found


~ >>> echo $PATH
~/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin


~ >>> cd ~/.local/bin


~/.local/bin >>> ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 jon  staff  102 Feb 23 19:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 jon  staff  170 Feb 23 19:25 ..
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jon  staff   39 Feb 23 19:25 pipsi -> /Users/me/.local/venvs/pipsi/bin/pipsi


~/.local/bin >>> cat pipsi
#!/Users/jon/.local/venvs/pipsi/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pipsi import cli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(cli())


~/.local/bin >>> pipsi
pipsi not found
```

I can't understand why the system just doesn't look right in the `~/.local/bin` directory and see the executable `pipsi` right there and run it.  Why does it report `pipsi not found`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the information presented in your question, your `$PATH` variable is set like this:

```
~ >>> echo $PATH
~/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Not too sure where you are setting your `$PATH` variable but I believe using the `~/` is not going to work in `$PATH` variable context; I don’t believe `~/` will properly expand to `/Users/jon/`. So I would recommend adjusting that:

```
~/.local/bin
```

So it is explicitly pointing to your home directory instead:

```
/Users/jon/.local/bin
```

Another great idea/suggestion based on Gordon Davisson’s comment is that somehow you are setting `~/.local/bin` with double quotes around it. Something like this:

```
PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

That `~/` placed within the double quotes will never get expanded to the full home path in that context. So instead try placing it *outside* of the quotes like this:

```
PATH=~/.local/bin:"$PATH"
```

Or perhaps even do something different and just use the `$HOME` variable within double quotes like this:

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then again, this is all based on how your actual `$PATH` variable specifics are handled in your user’s shell config. So adjust and tweak based on your specific needs.

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to setting `PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"`, and since the `~` is in quotes it doesn't get expanded to the actual home path. Instead, either use `PATH=~/.local/bin:"$PATH"` (`~` outside the quotes, so it gets expanded) or `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` (`$` expressions do get expanded in double-quotes).